# Dependency Injection when using static classes

Tags: dependency-injection, static, unity-container

**The general question** - I know that static classes should be avoided when using DI Containers, but in a project I am working on, one of the static classes is a constraint that I can not avoid. I am adding a method to that static class and I need to be able to inject a service that was created by a DI container. One approach was to add a static access to the container, but I feel that this is an anti pattern. I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way to inject a service into a static method.

**The Specific question** - I am developing a WPF attached property, and in the change callback I need to get an instance of a service that was registered using a Unity DI Container. The only solution I could think of was to add a static property to the bootstrapper, that would return the Unity Container.

```
    public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static UnityContainer Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _container;
        }
    }
```

But it feels wrong to store the container in a static field.

Are there other - more elegant - solutions?

Comment: Why cant you just use DI to inject the service you need into the class you need?

Comment: I am writing an attached property in WPF. Attached properties are static properties and static methods - That's just the way it is. And I need to inject the service into one of these static methods